# Guessing Game using for loop with C# Corrected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have written the code for the following program:

Inside the for loop block of code I need to perform the following logic:

1. Display to the screen “Enter Guess #: “ (e.g. “Enter Guess 2: “ where # is the number of
   the guess the user is on).
2. Get a number from the user and store the entered value in the input variable for testing.
3. Convert “input” to an integer (int32) and store in “guess”.
   d. Determine whether the entered number, now stored in “guess”, is the correct answer and take one of the following actions:

   - Display “You Win” if entered value is the answer and exit the loop.
   - Tell the user their guess is higher or lower than the answer.
4. If the user is not able to guess the answer in 5 guesses, then display “You Lose”

I getting an error with this code. Can anybody help me?

```
    int answer = 0, guess;
    string input = "" ;
    //Create an oject of the Random class
    Random number = new Random();
    answer = number.Next(1, 11);



    answer = number.Next(1, 11);
    Console.WriteLine("Select Randomly Number between 1 and 10 ");
 //   guess = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
    {                
        Console.Write("Enter Guess :");
        guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (guess > answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess is Higher");
        }
        else if (guess < answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess is Lower");
        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("You Won !!\t {0} is the correct number", guess);
            break;
            i = 6;

        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You Loose");
    Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0} ", answer);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: **WHERE** (on what line) do you get **WHAT** error?? We can't see and read your screen - you'll need to at least tell us that!!

Comment: I am getting error where                                         input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    input = guess;

Comment: This part is grand... `if (i == number) { if (i < number) { ... } }`  If i equals number, then i will never be greater than *or* less than number lol.  This code needs more help than just fixing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many errors .I can't explain all of it, but here is the fixed version, still not perfect but it should do what you want:

```
 int guess = 0, number;
 //Create an object of the Random class
 Random rnd = new Random();
 number  = rnd.Next(1, 11);
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
     Console.Write("Enter Guess :");
     guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if (guess > number)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Higher, try again");
     }
     else if (guess < number)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Lower,  try again");
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You Won !!\t {0} is the correct number", guess);
         i = 6;
     }
     if (i == 5)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("You Loose");
     }
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Update: Here is the list of your errors:

1. In below line `input` is a `string`, but you are trying to assign it to an `integer`:

   ```
   input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   ```
2. In this line, you are trying to overwrite `input`, why ?

   ```
   input = guess;
   ```
3. You are comparing `i` with `number` which is wrong because you should compare user's choice with random number and input is still a string,you can't compare an integer with a string directly.
4. In  this line `answer` is integer you are trying to concatenate it with a `string`:

   ```
   answer += (Console.ReadLine() + " ");
   ```

Probably there are some other errors but anyway,if you compare your code with the above code you will see solution of all these errors.

Comment: With this code, there is error message "Input string is not in correct format" where guess = convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline()); when is written second time at the end of the program

Comment: @user3341720 This code compiles prefectly for me.  the line should read exactly as his does, including capitalization.

Comment: @user3341720, if you just press return or enter something other than a number, you will get the "Input string is not in the correct format" error.  This is because `Convert.ToInt32` can not convert that string to a number.

Comment: @user3341720 if you enter a number, you won't see that error message.If you want to ignore invalid input, then use `int.TryParse` and check the returning result.if it's true that means number is valid, otherwise that means number isn't valid.

Comment: @David, if I don't enter anything then I am getting the "Input string....." error message

Comment: As per my logic mentioned above, I need to Get a number from the user and store the entered value in the input variable for testing.
Convert “input” to an integer (int32) and store in “guess”. The above mentioned code has directly used guess variable

Comment: The above code first generates a random number, then getting input from user for 6 times (max) and each time compare user's input with the random number.try again I updated my code, I write `Console.ReadLine` twice inside of for loop

Comment: The code is running ok but if you guessed the number correct , it still asks you enter the number ... Can anybody help me with this

Comment: @user3341720 add `i=6;` under the "You won.." line,it will break the loop

Comment: I have updated the code with everybody's help. But the code is showing one error at                              Console.WriteLine("You Loose \t The answer is {0}",guess);

Comment: the error message is "Use of unassigned local variable 'guess'

Comment: @user3341720 if you see that error, that means you **didn't assign a value to guess when you defining it**.

Comment: I am getting the following Output which is not correct:
Select Random Number between 1 and 10
Enter Guess: 6
Guess is Higher
Enter Guess: 5
Guess is Higher
Enter Guess:3
You Won ! 
You Loose
The Answer is 3